# Why is x not a Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

```
const instagramJSON = async function() {}

instagramJSON.get = async function(username) {

    if(!username) return new Error("Username needed!")

    const fetch = require("node-fetch"),
    url = "https://instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1"

    let res = await fetch(url).then(body => body.json())

    return res

}

exports = instagramJSON()
```

I dont know why this is happening, i am not very adv. at JavaScript so this could be an easy mistake i made, what could be the Problem?

```
TypeError: get is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dimitri\whatever stuff\test\test.js:3:13)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

Comment: Can you add the error message you are getting to your question please?

Comment: where is X in your code?

Comment: *I dont know why this is happening*. Why **what** is happening?

Comment: forgot the error

Comment: @ApolloDev You need to include the code importing and calling your module

Comment: @DelenaMalan TypeError: get is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dimitri\whatever stuff\test\test.js:3:13)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m

Comment: @Seblor const { get } = require("../lib/index.js")

console.log(get("thegstwins"))

Comment: No, please, don't put that information in a comments. Edit your question and add it there properly formatted so people can read it. It looks like you have ANSI terminal controls mixed in with the message. There's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61545507/edit) link below your question.

Comment: @lurker ok done

Answer (score 0):

`lib/index.js`

```
const instagramJSON = async function() {}

instagramJSON.get = ...

exports = instagramJSON()
```

`test/test.js`

```
const { get } = require("../lib/index.js")

console.log(get("thegstwins"))
```

There are two problems here.

- You're overwriting [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_exports) rather than [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_module). This is not the correct way to define an export object in CommonJS.
- You're invoking `instagramJSON()` and exporting its return value, which is a promise. `get` is a property of the *function*, not of the promise.

Fixing both of these issues, your `lib/index.js` would look like this:

```
const instagramJSON = async function() {}

instagramJSON.get = ...

module.exports = instagramJSON
```

Comment: The Error is still there

Comment: @ApolloDev I can't reproduce the error with these changes. Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] of the error including the changes suggested in my answer.